# How to instantiate AmqpTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I haven't been able to instantiate AmqpTemplate in a Spring Boot app; it keeps telling me it cannot be found.

I have a RestController which has a class which in turn has an autowired field AmqpTemplate, but it simply won't instantiate it.

```
@Component
public class Publisher {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;
```

Maybe something missing in SpringApplicatio? I bet not.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "co.com.bvc.serviceregistry.repository" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringRabbitMqPublisherApplication {
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Maven repo libraries were corrupted somehow, with bad signature, a warning the spring boot initialization was telling me.

I deleted the folders for those maven repos, clean, install and run spring boot and problem dissapeared.